# specific mysql update based on group by data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

This one has me stumpped.

I have 2 tables as so:

```
METERS
id | startTime

READINGS
id | meter_id | readingTime
```

What I want to do is update the `meters.startTime` to the lowest matching `readings.readingTime` in 1 sql query.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE Meters m
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT meter_id, MIN(reading_time) lowesttime
   FROM readings 
   GROUP BY meter_id
) r ON m.id = r.meter_id
SET m.starttime = r.lowesttime;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE METERS m SET startTime = (SELECT MIN(r.readingTime)
    FROM READINGS r
    WHERE r.meter_id = m.id)
WHERE m.id = your_id
```