# Update table based on aggregation from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I have a table `t1` like this:

```
Names    Drug 

Tom      A
Tom      A
Tom      B
Lily     B
Lily     B
```

and a table `t2` like this:

```
Names    Drug   COUNT(Drug)

Tom      A
Tom      B
Tom      C
Lily     A
Lily     B
```

I want to insert into the `COUNT(drug)` column of t2 the data from t1 after grouping by drug and name. The desired output of t2 looks like this:

```
Names    Drug   COUNT(Drug)

Tom      A      2
Tom      B      1
Tom      C      0
Lily     A      0
Lily     B      2
```

I am thinking about creating another table `t3` with the `GROUP BY drug, name` data from `t1` and then UPDATE `t2` based on `t3` but it is quite time-consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you have a complicated problem like this, you should always try to break it up into smaller pieces that you can solve, and put them back together.

For example, I would start by getting the name/drug counts from the first table like this:

```
SELECT name, drug, COUNT(*) AS numDrugs
FROM t1
GROUP BY name, drug;
```

Then, you can use this as a subquery when updating t2 by joining the two tables on the condition that name and drug match. You should use a leftjoin, and coalesce function to replace the values that don't exist with 0:

```
UPDATE t2
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT name, drug, COUNT(*) AS numDrugs
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY name, drug) t1 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.drug = t2.drug
SET drugCount = COALESCE(numDrugs, 0);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e8fe/1) example.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question can help you: [specific mysql update based on group by data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799177/specific-mysql-update-based-on-group-by-data)

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE t2
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT name, drug, count(*) num
   FROM t1 
   GROUP BY name, drug
) r ON  t2.name = r.name AND t2.drug = r.drug 
SET t2.count_drag = COALESCE(r.num, 0);
```

Comment: Note that it's possible a name,drug pair exists in t1 but not t2. For example, in OP's sample data, you will never update the rows for (Tom, C) and (Lily, A). You should try a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Looks good! The only thing it's still missing is that the left join will mean `r.num` is null for those values, not 0. Consider adding a check using `IF()` or `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`. Any would work, but I prefer the last one.